# Swapping using 2d arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to sort an array which contains names according to their length, but the following program gives a compiler error when I try to swap them using a function. Please help me identify my mistake.

```
void sort(char name1[][50])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(name1[i])>strlen(name1[i+1]))
        {
            char temp[50];
            temp=name1[i];  
            name1[i]=name1[i+1];
            name1[i+1]=temp;    
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use 'std::string' it will be more easy to do.

Comment: Note that this is not a complete sort.  You'd need to make more than one pass over the array to get the data fully sorted, in general.  If you passed in [ `"abcde"`, `"abcd"`, `"abc"`, `"ab"`, `"a"` ] then the output would be [ `"abcd"`, `"abc"`, `"ab"`, `"a"`, `"abcde"` ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strcpy()` to copy one array to other

```
void sort( char name1[][50])
{

    for(int i=0; i< 5;  i++)
    {
        if(strlen(name1[i])>strlen(name1[i+1]))
        {
        char temp[50];
        strcpy(temp,name1[i]);  
        strcpy(name1[i],name1[i+1]);
        strcpy(name1[i+1],temp);    
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you please let me know more of the simple things, why can we take input in the multidimensional array using both of the dimensions in the loop just like below:
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
  
  cout<<"enter name "<<i+1;
  cin>>names[i][50];
 }

Comment: @mwbee you need to write cin>>names[i], because you are entering the name which is referred by names[i]. for example names[0], refers to the first name, names[1] to the second name.

Comment: @mwbee you can mark it as correct if it was helpful, to make it more useful for other users

Comment: @mwbee Please consider using `strncpy` instead, it is particularly simple to do so when all the strings have the sane max length.

Comment: Thankyou guys. Really helped alot.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy` to copy c-string. First copy the first string into the temp string, then copy the second into the first, and finally the temp into the second string.

```
strcpy(temp,name1[i]);

strcpy(name1[i],name1[i+1]);

strcpy(name1[i+1],temp);
```

Comment: thanks, can you please let me know more of the simple things, why can we take input in the multidimensional array using both of the dimensions in the loop just like below: for(int i=0; i<5; i++) { cout<<"enter name "<<i+1; cin>>names[i][50]; }